# iRobot Create 2 serial battery power

Tags: raspberry-pi, irobot-create, serial, roomba

I don's seem to be able to get any battery power from Create 2. I spliced the original cable it came with, and tried to use the power from red/purple(+) and yellow/orange(-) to power a Raspberry Pi2, with no luck. While the serial-to-USB cable still works, and I am able to command the robot via Python, there seems to be no power coming on the red/purple cables. I tried with a multimeter with no luck, even as I moved the device from passive/safe/full modes. There is no power even when Create 2 is charging/docked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there's no guarantee the wire colors in the iRobot cable match the colors in the cable made by Tensility. Step one is to get an ohm meter and see if the colors match the pins you expect. If they do, I wonder if you accidentally blew the resettable fuse? See the discussion at the end of the section entitled External Serial Port Mini-DIN Pinout on [page 3](http://www.irobotweb.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/iRobot_Roomba_600_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf). Depending on what you've plugged in, you may have pulled more than 200mA. Wait a bit for the fuse to cool, and then with nothing connected to the robot, (carefully) jam a multimeter between pins 6 and 1 on the connector and see if you get battery voltage. If you do, plug your cable in, with nothing attached to the cable but the voltmeter, and see if you get battery voltage where you'd expect it. If that checks out, put an ammeter between the battery power wires and your Pi, preferably in peak detect mode.

Good luck; I hope you have a multimeter.

<sup>Please note that while I'm an iRobot employee, the postings on this site are my own and don't necessarily represent iRobot's positions, strategies, or opinions.</sup>

Comment: Indeed the cable did not match the colour code iRobot had in their docs, even if the cable came with the Create 2. Moreover the Vcc cable was not connected at all as far as I could figure out, I assume they focused on the connection to PC USB, which would not require the batter power. Anyway, I read again the iRobot docs, gave up using the cable and the 7-pin plug and used breadboard type male connectors with individual cables to provide Pi2 with both Vcc power (DC2DC converter) and USB serial access (FTTDI). The multimeter was my friend indeed :) + https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22rsKi0f6YM